# How can I convert this small code snippet from aspx to MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here's the source:

```
<% string[] roles = ViewData["Roles"] as string[]; 
                   if (roles != null && roles.Length > 0) {%>
            <p>
                <label for="roleName">
                    Role:</label>
                <% foreach (string role in roles) { %>
                <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, role) %>&nbsp; <span>
                    <%: role%></span>
                <% } %>
            </p>
            <%} %>
```

Here's my attempt:

```
 @{
        string[] roles = ViewData["Roles"] as string[]; 
        if (roles != null && roles.Length > 0) {
            <p>
                <label for="roleName">Role:</label>
                foreach (string role in roles) {    
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, @role)&nbsp; <span>@role</span>
                    }
            </p>
        }
    }
```

The problem is that at run time I get the following error message:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'role' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Line 41:                 <label for="roleName">Role:</label>
Line 42:                 foreach (string role in roles) {    
Line 43:                     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, @role)&nbsp; <span>@role</span>
Line 44:             </p>
Line 45:         }
```

Can someone see what's wrong. I tried but it seems there is something wrong with my attempt. So far I also tried change line 43 to:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, role)&nbsp; <span>@(role)</span>

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, role)&nbsp; <span>@role</span>
```

Both still don't work :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (string role in roles) {    
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, @role)&nbsp; <span>@role</span>
}
```

should be

```
@foreach (string role in roles) {    
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, role) <span>@role</span>
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this gives the same error message: <label for="roleName">Role:</label>
Line 42:                 foreach (string role in roles) {    
Line 43:                     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, role) <span>@role</span>
Line 44:                 }

Comment: Because you didnt put the @ before the foreach as I stated on my answer

Comment: Just found the solution. I needed an @ before the foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, @role)&nbsp; <span
```

should be

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, role)&nbsp;
```

the @role is correct. but no @ sign is required in the RadioButtonFor(...) call

Comment: " @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, role)&nbsp; <span>@role</span>" Unfortunately this still does not work. I get the same message.

Comment: same fault? the @role was the part that should have been flagged.

Comment: Just found the solution. I needed an @ before the foreach

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@{
    string[] roles = ViewData["Roles"] as string[]; 
    if (roles != null && roles.Length > 0) {
    <p>
        <label for="roleName">Role:</label>
        @foreach (string role in roles) {    
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, @role)@:&nbsp;<span>@role</span>
        }
    </p>
    }
}
```

or you can use:

```
@{
    string[] roles = ViewData["Roles"] as string[]; 
}
@if (roles != null && roles.Length > 0) {
<p>
    <label for="roleName">Role:</label>
    @foreach (string role in roles) {    
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleName, @role)@:&nbsp;<span>@role</span>
    }
</p>
}
```